# Capture by value/reference and early/late binding

Tags: c++, lambda, reference, binding

Is *capture by value* (`x` below) an early binding and *capture by reference* (`y` below) a late binding in C++ lambdas, or are they both early bindings—the first by value and the second by reference?

```cpp
#include <iostream>


int main() {
    auto x = 0, y = 0;
    auto lambda = [x, &y]() { std::cout << x << ' ' << y; };
    x = 1, y = 1;
    lambda();  // outputs: 0 1
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Early and late binding are used almost exclusively for method call semantics. As such, the question doesn't really make sense.

Comment: @SebastianRedl Could you share some references supporting this?

Comment: @SebastianRedl Early and late binding is relevant for anything that has a name in your code whether it’s method, free function or data. The fact that the term is mostly associated with functions and methods and often in an object oriented context doesn’t invalidate this question at all. See this nice overview of the different concepts relating to binding: https://www.cs.iusb.edu/~dvrajito/teach/c311/c311_3_scope.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The lambda defines a [closure](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(computer_programming)), which is an anonymous function together with an environment composed of captured variables.

The binding of captured variables happens at the moment the lambda is defined and uses the variables of the scope in which it was defined. **This is early binding**. As you said, early binding of a value and of a reference in your example.

As a consequence of early binding, if you would enclose your lambda call in its own scope with another x and y variable, the capture would still use the original x value and the reference to the y of the scope of the definition:

```
#include <iostream>


int main() {
    auto x = 0, y = 0;
    auto lambda = [x, &y]() { std::cout << x << ' ' << y; };
    x = 1, y = 1;
    {
        auto x = 27, y = 2;
        lambda();  // still outputs: 0 1
    }
    return 0;
}
```

[Online demo](https://ideone.com/FTA7Jq)

Another consequence is that if the variable captured by reference no longer exists when you invoke the lambda you have undefined behaviour.

Late binding would work differently: the capture would not bind to y in main(). It would bind to an identifier corresponding to y. The binding would be done when the lambda would be invoked. In my example, the binding would be done with the inner y, and the output would be 0 2.

Comment: With your example it is crystal clear Christophe, thanks for this amazing answer. Not only did you answer my question, but also the subsidiary answers that I had in mind. I still have a few more though: 1. If early binding is *binding by value* or *binding by reference*, could we say that late binding is *binding by name*. 2. The following Python code uses late binding, right? `f = lambda: x; x = 1; print(f())`

Comment: @Maggyero: "*If early binding is binding by value or binding by reference, could we say that late binding is binding by name.*" I think you misunderstood his point. Both of those are "early binding" but only by-default; the early/late binding nomenclature simply isn't *meaningful* in this context. The use of a reference is not "early binding"; a function which takes a reference to a polymorphic base class would represent "late binding".

Comment: @Maggyero I used a name binding in my example of late binding as example, because it’s easier to explain how the binding could be resolved to find a different y. But it does not have to be like that. It could work with any indirection mechanism that could be performed at the time of execution of the lambda. Nicolas gives an example of late binding in the case of a function: virtual tables are an indirection mechanism that allows late binding without name. C++ has no late binding for variables at all. It is something that you’d need to emulate.

Comment: @Maggyero I wanted to add a wikipedia reference, but the articles about early binding refers to inheritance, and late binding is explained only for functions/operation, completely ignoring that binding of capture variables or even scope variables can also be late, as for example [in lisp](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Dynamic-Binding.html). Better refer to CS literature on this particular one.

Comment: Sorry my question 1 was very poorly formulated. Since we gave two examples of early bindings, one to a value (by storing the value in the function environment), and one to a reference (by storing the reference in the function environment), I was wondering if late binding could be seen as early binding to a name (by storing the name in the function environment). But I don’t think this view is interesting as I don’t think it is implemented like this. Rather I think we store nothing in the environment for late binding. So as you said there is no binding or "capture" until the function is applied.

Comment: @NicolBolas Yes the early/late binding characterisation in terms of binding by value,reference/name in my question 1 was incorrect. Actually I think there are orthogonal concepts and there is no such thing as "binding by name" like I claimed, since binding means storing the relation name–entity in an environment and you never (I guess) store the relation name–name. Now you said that the early/late binding distinction is not meaningful in the context of lambdas because they always use early binding. I disagree because this is a language-wide distinction, not an entity-wide distinction.

Comment: @Christophe I think you forgot my question 2 :). And here is a new one: 3. Can we say that the `x` and `y` in the C++ program of my post are *bound variables* since they are bound to a value and a reference, respectively, and that the `x` in the Python program of my question 2 is a *free variable* (I think that free variables do not exist in C++)? In other words, are bound variables early bound and free variables late bound?

Comment: @Maggyero I didn’t forget 2, but I’m not a Python guru and not sure to fully master its semantics when it comes to subtle subjects. My inderstanding from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12919278/3723423) is that free variables are variables late binding and binding by name. In C++ every variable is bound at compile time and there is no real equivalent of a free variable. You’d have to emulate this using some symbol table (e.g. a map).

Comment: @Maggyero the technically closest native c++ feature would be an external variable, that is defined in a dynamically linked library loaded at runtime. However this is still far from a free variable since the binding is done once, does not depend on the surrounding context and moreover the fully qualified variable name must be unique.

Comment: Thanks for your input Chris, I am glad that we have the same understanding.

Comment: Actually Python’s free variables do not seem to have the strict late binding property that you are referring to in your answer, where a name binding occurring in *any* code block can be used for name resolution: indeed executing `def f(): return x` followed by `def g(): x = 0; return f()` and `g()` raises `NameError: name 'x' is not defined`. They have a loose late binding property, where only a name binding occurring in an *outer* code block of that introducing the free variable can be used for name resolution: indeed executing `def f(): return x` followed by `x = 0` and `f()` returns 0.

Comment: In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63312608/2326961), @MisterMiyagi pointed out that what we have been referring to as *early binding/late binding* is more precisely termed [*lexical scoping (a.k.a. static scoping)/dynamic scoping*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_(computer_science)#Lexical_scoping_vs._dynamic_scoping). So Python does not have late binding (dynamic scoping) but early binding (lexical scoping). The fact that it allows [forward references](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forward_declaration#Forward_reference) (contrary to C++) has nothing to do with late binding.

Comment: @Maggyero As said, I’m not a python guru. Nevertheless, I think that lexical/dynamic scoping (i.e the rules that apply to resolve naming conflicts) is orthogonal to the binding strategy (when the link is done): Depending on the language semantic, a compiler could at compilation time identify which is the variable to use for dynamic scoping and do early binding. The JIT compiling technology has postponed  « early » to be relatively late. but in LISP for example, where a function could self-modify, this is difficult to realize making late binding a necessity.

Comment: I think you are mostly right, I have taken a little shortcut when I said lexical/dynamic scoping = early/late binding. The article actually states: "Lexical resolution can be determined at compile time, and is also known as **early binding**, while dynamic resolution can in general only be determined at run time, and thus is known as **late binding**."

Comment: @Maggyero when I learned compiler design, JIT compiler didn’t exist. The definition of early and late binding were straightforward : if the compiler couldn’t bind the name at compilation, it was late. But now, JIT compilers make the frontier more difficult to grasp: what is done by the jit compiler? and what is done by the runtime environment? So it needs implementation (dependent?) information to decide.

Comment: Chris, on the same topic, can I request your expertise on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63357996/2326961)?

Comment: @Maggyero Interesting question;  My knowledge of JavaScript is rather superficial, but after studying the specs about bindings,  experimenting a little,  and lloking for confirmation in at least one article, I think I have provided a decent answer.